# Login on a Webpage via QML-App

Tags: ubuntu-touch, qml

I am trying to write an App for Ubuntu Touch on a Nexus 4 using QML and the Ubuntu SDK. The App should do what I usually do via Internetbrowser: Login on a Webpage, and then see the data on the next page.
How can I write that in QML?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you please detail what type of login do you need (openid? or local accounts) and what is the content of your app, i.e the next page (a webview ?)

Answer (score 0):

Exists in QML Webkit

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwebkit-index.html

Most do not know if it works on Ubuntu SDK (Ubuntu Touch)